# KafkaRecord cannot be cast to [B

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm trying to process the data streaming from Apache Kafka using the **Python SDK** for Apache Beam with the Flink runner. After running Kafka 2.4.0 and Flink 1.8.3, I follow these steps:

1) Compile and run Beam 2.16 with Flink 1.8 runner.

```sh
git clone --single-branch --branch release-2.16.0 https://github.com/apache/beam.git beam-2.16.0
cd beam-2.16.0
nohup ./gradlew :runners:flink:1.8:job-server:runShadow -PflinkMasterUrl=localhost:8081 &
```

2) Run the Python pipeline.

```py
from apache_beam import Pipeline
from apache_beam.io.external.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions([
        '--runner=FlinkRunner',
        '--flink_version=1.8',
        '--flink_master_url=localhost:8081',
        '--environment_type=LOOPBACK',
        '--streaming'
    ])) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | 'read' >> ReadFromKafka({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'}, ['test'])  # [BEAM-3788] ???
        )
        result = pipeline.run()
        result.wait_until_finish()
```

3) Publish some data to Kafka.

```sh
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>{"hello":"world!"}
```

---

The Python script throws this error:

```sh
[flink-runner-job-invoker] ERROR org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.jobsubmission.JobInvocation - Error during job invocation BeamApp-USER-somejob. org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed. (JobID: xxx)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:268)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:483)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkExecutionEnvironments$BeamFlinkRemoteStreamEnvironment.executeRemotely(FlinkExecutionEnvironments.java:360)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.execute(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:310)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkStreamingPortablePipelineTranslator$StreamingTranslationContext.execute(FlinkStreamingPortablePipelineTranslator.java:173)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineRunner.runPipelineWithTranslator(FlinkPipelineRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineRunner.run(FlinkPipelineRunner.java:80)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.jobsubmission.JobInvocation.runPipeline(JobInvocation.java:78)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:265)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord cannot be cast to [B
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:41)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.LengthPrefixCoder.encode(LengthPrefixCoder.java:56)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.ValueWithRecordId$ValueWithRecordIdCoder.encode(ValueWithRecordId.java:105)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.ValueWithRecordId$ValueWithRecordIdCoder.encode(ValueWithRecordId.java:81)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.encode(WindowedValue.java:578)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.encode(WindowedValue.java:529)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:82)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(CoderUtils.java:66)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(CoderUtils.java:51)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.clone(CoderUtils.java:141)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.types.CoderTypeSerializer.copy(CoderTypeSerializer.java:67)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:577)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollect(StreamSourceContexts.java:305)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:394) at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.io.UnboundedSourceWrapper.emitElement(UnboundedSourceWrapper.java:341)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.wrappers.streaming.io.UnboundedSourceWrapper.run(UnboundedSourceWrapper.java:283)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:93)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:57)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:97)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StoppableSourceStreamTask.run(StoppableSourceStreamTask.java:45)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:302)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
        ... 1 more
ERROR:root:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord cannot be cast to [B
[flink-runner-job-invoker] INFO org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.BeamFileSystemArtifactRetrievalService - Manifest at/tmp/artifacts0k1mnin0/somejob/MANIFEST has 0 artifact locations
[flink-runner-job-invoker] INFO org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.artifact.BeamFileSystemArtifactStagingService - Removed dir /tmp/artifacts0k1mnin0/job_somejob/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    run()
  File "main.py", line 37, in run
    result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/home/USER/beam/lib/python3.5/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 439, in wait_until_finish self._job_id, self._state, self._last_error_message()))
RuntimeError: Pipeline BeamApp-USER-somejob failed in state FAILED: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord cannot be cast to [B
```

I tried [other deserializers available in Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/package-tree.html) but they did not work: `Couldn't infer Coder from class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer`. This error is originating from [this piece of code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/90ada50f8c8b2797c30aae0e032d4b18cbc5b69c/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L437).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You provide a lot of context (you mention multiple tools for instance) , but this makes it harder to know where the problem lies. Please narrow it down reduce the code to a bare minimum that allows people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I removed the unnecessary details. My question should be much more clear now. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Is ByteArrayCoder the default value for Kafka reader?

Comment: @cricket_007 It's `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer`

Comment: That is for a producer, not a Consumer. Looking at the source code you linked to, it gets a Coder class from the deserializer, which is what Beam uses to read records

Comment: @cricket_007 When I pass any coder from `org.apache.beam.sdk.coders`, I get this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build transform beam:external:java:kafka:read:v1 from spec urn: "beam:external:java:kafka:read:v1" ... Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't resolve coder for Deserializer ...`

Comment: Based on the code you linked, I saw only bytes and integers or longs deserializers as valid options. I guess you could use leave it as byte deserializer, then map that result to a String

Comment: @cricket_007 Like I told you, whatever deserializer I pass, Beam throws the `Couldn't infer Coder from ...` error.

Comment: Can you please manually specify a key and value deserailizer? https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/90ada50f8c8b2797c30aae0e032d4b18cbc5b69c/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L411 Where in your question did you try that?

Comment: Or manually set the coder https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/90ada50f8c8b2797c30aae0e032d4b18cbc5b69c/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L560

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm specifying key and value deserializers like this: `ReadFromKafka(key_deserializer='org.apache...', value_deserializer='org.apache...)'`. That's when I get `Couldn't resolve coder` error. Am I doing something wrong? AFAIK, there isn't any other `withKeyDeserializerAndCoder` alternative for the Python SDK.

Comment: Looking at the Python sdk, I see `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer` is actually the default. Honestly, I'm not sure myself. I personally am just interested in Beam, but I would try getting JMX debugging enabled in the Flink source and see what property is being loaded

Comment: @deebug, I tried was successfully able to reproduce it on flink. I think its a bug. Would you mind opening a jira issue here https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7850

Comment: @Ankur Thank you for giving it a shot. It seems like a bug, you can find my issue here: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is my first encounter with Apache Beam project.

It seems that Kafka consumer support is quite fresh thing in Beam (at least in Python interface) according to this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6730). Apparently, it seems that there is [still problem with `FlinkRunner` combined with this new API](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7870). Even though your code is technically correct it will not run correctly on Flink. [There is a patch available](https://github.com/mxm/beam/commit/b31cf99c75b3972018180d8ccc7e73d311f4cfed) which seems more like a quickfix than final solution to me. It requires recompilation and thus is not something I would propose using on production. If you are just getting started with technology and don't want to be blocked then feel free to try it out.